# Local time validation with daylight

Tags: java, validation, time, dst

We have a requirement in java to validate the local time before it is passed to scheduler like quartz. System receives London local time say 01:30 AM but this time in not valid on March 26 2017 (daylight savings).
How do I write a code to output below results?

Input

```
12:30, 01:30, 02:30
```

Output

```
Mar 26 2017 12:30   ->  Valid, GMT   
Mar 26 2017 01:30   ->  Invalid, NA   
Mar 26 2017 02:30   ->  Valid, BST
```

Comment: `01:30` is only invalid on `Mar 26 2017`. Today is not Mar 26, 2017, so with only time inputs, it is valid. --- Also, what is `NA` and `BST`, and why is `02:30` validated against `BST`, but `12:30` is validated against `GMT`? --- Your question is unclear.

Comment: @Andreas the point is that 26/3/2017 is the date when UK switches from GMT to BST - that is, daylight savings starts.  On that particular day, there's no such time as 01:30 because the clock jumps forward from 01:00 to 02:00.  OP is asking for a way to detect whether a given date/time is WITHIN the daylight savings season (and therefore should be understood as BST) or OUTSIDE the daylight savings season (and therefore should be understood as GMT) or neither.  I find this question _very_ clear.

Comment: @DavidWallace Question is entirely unclear, because input is only `01:30`, not `Mar 26 2017 01:30`. Without a date, the question is unanswerable. and OP doesn't say what date to use, not even "today". --- Also, `BST` is [Bougainville Standard Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/bst-bougainville). Everybody knows that. Or maybe everybody doesn't know what BST means. Again, question is unclear.

Comment: Inputs are 'March 26 2017, [12:30, 01:30, 02:30], ZoneId is 'Europe/London'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you start with a LocalDateTime then you can test to see if it's valid for scheduling by seeing if a given timezone reports that there are valid offsets for the time. This info is available in the [ZoneRules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getValidOffsets-java.time.LocalDateTime-) class.

Here's some sample code:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
    ZoneId londonZone = tz.toZoneId();

    String springAhead = "2017-03-26T01:30";

    assertFalse(isValidForScheduling(londonZone, LocalDateTime.parse(springAhead)));

    String fallBack = "2017-10-29T01:30";

    assertFalse(isValidForScheduling(londonZone, LocalDateTime.parse(fallBack)));
}

private boolean isValidForScheduling(ZoneId zoneId, LocalDateTime ldt) {
    ZoneRules rules = zoneId.getRules();

    List<ZoneOffset> validOffsets = rules.getValidOffsets(ldt);
    return validOffsets.size() == 1;
}
```

If the list of validOffsets is empty then it's not a valid time. If there is more than 1 entry then the time occurs multiple times in that zone (the case of putting the clocks back). If there's a single entry, then it's a regular time.

You'd probably want to fail on an empty list and warn on a list with multiple entries.

Comment: Very close. But 01:30 on Oct 29 is a valid time but happens twice on that day.

Comment: The toy method above is "isValidForScheduling" not "isValidTime". You can change the semantics, name, and test of the list size. If the app is for scheduling, then as I said at the end of my answer, you'd probably want to warn the user if the job will execute multiple times. The Quartz docs cover this.

Answer (score 0):

The below code errors only for March 26 2017 1AM-2AM. I didnt like the way it is written. Can it be refactored?  This doesn't error on Oct 29 2017.
`LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 3, 26, hours, minutes);`
`ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));`
`if ( zonedDateTime.getHour() != localDateTime.getHour() ) {`
   `System.out.println("MISMATCH!!!");`
`}`